# Problems with nodeS CORS

Tags: node.js, http, browser, cors

I am trying to display a dicom with NODEJS but the browser throws me this problem

> XMLHttpRequest can not load http: // localhost: 8080 / wado?
>   RequestType = WADO & studyUID = 1.2.840.113704.1.111.5 ... 26513.429 &
>   contentType = application% 2Fdicom & transferSyntax =
>   1.2.840.10008.1.2. In 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http: // localhost: 3000' is
>   therefore not allowed access.

Then install npm the package cors

And here I leave my code part of my code app.js

```
Var express = require ('express');
Var cors = require ('cors')
App.use (cors ())


App.listen (3000, function () {
  Console.log ('listening on 3000')
})
```

Also try adding this in app.js

```
App.use (function (req, res, next) {
  Res.header ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  Res.header ("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  Next ();
});
```

But the browser still displays the error:

> XMLHttpRequest can not load http: // localhost: 8080 / wado?
>   RequestType = WADO & studyUID = 1.2.840.113704.1.111.5 ... 26513.429 &
>   contentType = application% 2Fdicom & transferSyntax =
>   1.2.840.10008.1.2. In 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http: // localhost: 3000' is
>   therefore not allowed access.

I have doubt because I also use the route index.js which I leave here

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var cors = require('cors')
/*var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();*/
var mysql = require('mysql');
router.use(cors({origin: 'http://localhost:3000'}));
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
 res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I'm sorry for my English

Comment: if your server is listening on port 3000 what is listening on 8080 ?

Comment: The error messages cited in the question indicate the port 8080 server (whatever it is…) is the one where you need to need to configure to return the Access-Control-Allow-Origin etc response headers. Whatever CORS configuration you do on the port 3000 server isn’t going to make any difference as far as fixing that error. Because that port 3000 server is the one *sending* the cross-origin requests, right? The CORS config needs to be set on the server *receiving* the cross-origin requests.

Comment: My NODEJS application runs on port 3000 and dcm4chee with the WADO service to get the DICOM runs on port 8080; Also try to use cors pointing to 8080 like this: app.use (cors ({origin: 'http: // localhost: 8080'})) but still the browser responds with the same problem

Comment: Could you give me some example of how to configure the cors? Please, dcm4chee is the one that runs on port 8080 is the one that provides the dicom and my application in NODEJS runs on the port 3000 is the one that receives the dicom.

Comment: @M.Node Details are in the answer I added. Basically unless you know how to configure the Dcm4chee server to send the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header, you need to put a proxy in between and use that.

Comment: My problem comes from port 8080, as I add Access-Control-Allow-Origin to port 8080 which is where the dcm4chee service works which provides me the DICOM files, my application works on port 3000 and already enable the cors in the port 3000, but as I enable the CORS in port 8080 where the service that provides the DICOM images works, that is my question.

Answer (score 0):

For security purpose browsers don't allow cross origin requests under normal conditions. 
Your page is loading from `localhost:3000`, which defines the origin as it is the first request. Your code is trying to load data from another service running on port- 8080, that is different from origin. So basically you need to enable cors on the service running on port 8080 as it is the external source.

Comment: I do not understand very well, I understand that I should enable cors of port 8080, but what I do not understand is how to do it, I mean I have to do it in NODEJS in app.js pointing to port 8080. or do some external config in dcm4chee that is You dicom provider?

Comment: My problem comes from port 8080, as I add Access-Control-Allow-Origin to port 8080 which is where the dcm4chee service works which provides me the DICOM files, my application works on port 3000 and already enable the cors in the port 3000, but as I enable the CORS in port 8080 where the service that provides the DICOM images works, that is my question.

Comment: @M.Node You have to enable CORS on DICOM service port and not on 3000, because node service running at port 3000 is your origin. You can transfer data with your origin without any problem. But when your browser tries to make request to port 8080, that is not your origin app. So, service running on port 8080 must tell browser that it is ready to share resources with different origins. If port 8080 doesn't say that, then your browser will consider that you are trying to steal some data from other domains and restrict it.